# How can I change the code to make items bigger?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I found a person who posted how to change code with .json files in resource packs to make items look bigger in your hand, but I would like to know how to do the same thing with the appearance of the item when it's on the ground (for map making purposes). Can someone show me how to do this? The code I found to change hand display is down below, if there is a way to go off of that.

```
{
    "parent": "item/generated",
    "display": {
        "thirdperson_righthand": {
            "rotation": [ 0, -90, 55 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 4.0, 0.5 ],
            "scale": [ 2, 2, 2 ]
        },
        "thirdperson_lefthand": {
            "rotation": [ 0, 90, -55 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 4.0, 0.5 ],
            "scale": [ 2, 2, 2 ]
        },
        "firstperson_righthand": {
            "rotation": [ 0, -90, 25 ],
            "translation": [ 1.13, 3.2, 1.13 ],
            "scale": [ 2, 2, 2 ]
        },
        "firstperson_lefthand": {
            "rotation": [ 0, 90, -25 ],
            "translation": [ 1.13, 3.2, 1.13 ],
            "scale": [ 2, 2, 2 ]
        }
    },
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "items/diamond_sword"
    }
}
```

Comment: why is this downvoted? its a good question.

Comment: @DanZ I would assume that the downvotes were due to the bad formatting prior to Rudolf's edit.

Comment: My downvote is because no effort has been displayed. No attempt has been made to modify the code found to suit his purposes. Just, here's what I found, make it do what I want.

Comment: @Frank, I had tried editing Minecraft source code. You get lost in it after some research. It's... chaos. I understand your point of view as a gamer in general, but as a Minecraft mod developer (which I am) I'd say this is a good question with some research behind it (where the hell did he find that peice of code in the .minecraft folder?).

Comment: @Rudolf He didn't find it; someone else did. Hence the down vote.

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek Just pointing out: it's not code and isn't directly from Minecraft's source. It's a JSON structure, representing a custom model used in Minecraft resource packs (to which we have a relevant tag that is already applied to the question, so should not be closed).

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek thank you so much for editing the code in the question (I didn't know how to do that) and for the awesome feedback about the question but do you know of a way to change the appearance of an item with the .json code so it looks bigger when dropped?

Comment: It's alright man! Thanks for all the help! And if you ever find a way to do this even if you coincidentally stumble upon a way to do it could you please let me know?

Answer (score 14):

This is the parent class of blocks (`../models/block/block.json`), which has more options for displaying them. You could use these settings for specific items or add them to their parent class.

```
{
    "display": {
        "gui": {
            "rotation": [ 30, 225, 0 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 0, 0],
            "scale":[ 0.625, 0.625, 0.625 ]
        },
        "ground": {
            "rotation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 3, 0],
            "scale":[ 0.25, 0.25, 0.25 ]
        },
        "fixed": {
            "rotation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 0, 0],
            "scale":[ 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 ]
        },
        "thirdperson_righthand": {
            "rotation": [ 75, 45, 0 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 2.5, 0],
            "scale": [ 0.375, 0.375, 0.375 ]
        },
        "firstperson_righthand": {
            "rotation": [ 0, 45, 0 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
            "scale": [ 0.40, 0.40, 0.40 ]
        },
        "firstperson_lefthand": {
            "rotation": [ 0, 225, 0 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
            "scale": [ 0.40, 0.40, 0.40 ]
        }
    }
}
```

You can add parent properties (block/item class for example) to child elements (a specific block/item) in order to overrule them. Even if they are not in the child's json file you can put them there in order to make your changes. You could even add more settings to the block/item class, if the base interface of them supports them.

An example chain of command (from child to parent) would be:

`item/crafting_table` <- `block/crafting_table` <- `block/cube` <- `block/block`

Changes to `block/block` would apply to (inherited by) the whole chain, while changes to `item/crafting_table` will only apply to this item type.

---

How to use the info provided above

[image: Crafting Stick]

---

### Beginners guide: resizing items

To get started you need the following tools (they're all free):

- Text editor (I used [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for this)
- [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or similar
- [JSON parser](http://jsonparseronline.com/) to double check for errors

**If you don't have any JSON files...**

1. Locate your minecraft folder (usually `%appdata%/.minecraft`).
2. Open the jar file of the version you want to work with
   (`./versions/1.x.x/1.x.x.jar`) with 7-Zip.
3. Extract the contents of `assets\minecraft\models`, which should be two folders (`block` & `item`). They contain all the JSON files you need.

Ok, you're good to go. As described above, you'll need some extra properties from the parent class. I'm using a **crafting table**, since I already used it as example.

1. Locate the file `block/block.json` and copy the `display` block into your clipboard.
2. Now open the JSON file of the item you wish to edit. (`block/crafting_table.json` in my example)
3. Paste the code you copied into this file and make your changes. Your file should end up like this:

   ```
   {
       "parent": "block/cube",
       "textures": {
           "particle": "blocks/crafting_table_front",
           "down": "blocks/planks_oak",
           "up": "blocks/crafting_table_top",
           "north": "blocks/crafting_table_front",
           "east": "blocks/crafting_table_side",
           "south": "blocks/crafting_table_side",
           "west": "blocks/crafting_table_front"
       },
       "display": {
           "gui": {
               "rotation": [ 30, 225, 0 ],
               "translation": [ 0, 0, 0],
               "scale":[ 1.3, 0.3, 0.3 ]
           },
           "ground": {
               "rotation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
               "translation": [ 0, 3, 0],
               "scale":[ 0.015, 0.015, 0.015 ]
           },
           "fixed": {
               "rotation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
               "translation": [ 0, 0, 0],
               "scale":[ 1.5, 2.0, 1.0 ]
           },
           "thirdperson_righthand": {
               "rotation": [ 75, 45, 0 ],
               "translation": [ 0, 2.5, 0],
               "scale": [ 0.5, 2.0, 0.5 ]
           },
           "firstperson_righthand": {
               "rotation": [ 0, 45, 0 ],
               "translation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
               "scale": [ 1.04, 0.04, 1.04 ]
           },
           "firstperson_lefthand": {
               "rotation": [ 0, 225, 0 ],
               "translation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
               "scale": [ 0.40, 0.40, 0.40 ]
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Code blocks of the same hierarchy are separated with a comma, so make sure you have one in this part:

   ```
   },
   "display": {
   ```
5. Save the file(s) when you're done.
6. Double check your code by opening the JSON parser I suggested above. Paste your code into it and if it doesn't show any errors you can go on. If you did something wrong you'd probably end up with this:
   (Yes, I forgot the comma)
   [image: Error]

**Now where to put the newly created item enhancements?**

- By creating a resource pack...
- We'll need 7-Zip again.

  1. The base dir will be **assets**, which you'll find in the structure you extracted from the jar file in step 1. This will be our entry point.
  2. To save work and space and other things we don't want to copy all the files we didn't change, so create a new folder named `assets` on your desktop or any other desired location.
  3. Inside `assets`, create the same folder structure you find in the extracted one:
     `- minecraft
     -- models
     --- block
     --- item (if applicable)`
  4. Copy your changed JSON files in the folder they are originally from (block to block, item to item)
  5. Create a file named `pack.mcmeta` with the following code:

     ```
     {
         "pack": {
             "pack_format": 1,
             "description": "something"
         }
     }
     ```
  6. Create a ZIP archive with 7-Zip with `assets` as its base and the `pack.mcmeta` file right next to it. If you open the ZIP file you should see the assets folder and the pack file right there.
  7. Put the ZIP file in your `.minecraft/resourcepacks` folder and start minecraft
  8. Load the resource pack like you would normally do. It should be compatible with existing ones.
  9. If you did it right, Excalibur awaits you. 
     [image: Big Sword]

Once you have done all this, the next steps will be easier. You can just drag and drop newly edited files into your existing archive in your resourcepacks folder. There is no need to (un-)zip everything all over again.

Comment: How exactly would one change the size of just one type of item, or just one single item?

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek by putting the same into the child class of exactly that item. The changes to the parent class apply to all childs of that parent while changes to the childs apply only to them. Changes to child properties overrule their parent properties.

Comment: Yep, the bounty belongs to you, and I'll award it when it ends. In the meanwhile, could you add more information to make your answer noob-friendly - is any third-party software needed? Do you need to copy-paste the whole json file, of just change the info in an already existing one? Is there any software that does this for the user? (And so on) Thanks!

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek sure, I can do that.

Comment: Congratulations! You just won the bounty! (alongside to 11 upvotes and a badge)  :-)

Comment: No problem - I'm here to help get answers, not reputation. I put a bounty, so this doesn't end like one of the many unanswered questions, and you won ;-)

Comment: I tried doing this with a nether wart but it didn't resize it no matter what I did to the "ground" part (that's the part I want resized so it's bigger on the ground) what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, this approach is only for items you hold. For blocks on the ground it's different.

Answer (score -1):

I've got 2 solutions for your issue. The 1st one uses a software, and the 2nd must be applied directly in the concerned file.

[Blockbench](https://blockbench.net/) is a great tool for modifying JSON files and making your own JSON models. You can scale and position items in many situations, like offhand, main hand, ground, head, item frame and GUI. All changes are done using simple sliders that tell you what they do. It works for **1.12** and up and is available for Windows, Windows portable, Linux and Mac, as well as a web app.

I've been using it for years to make resource packs.

---

If you don't want to or can't use Blockbench, values you need to change are in the section:

```
"ground": {
     "rotation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
     "translation": [ 0, 3, 0],
     "scale":[ 0.015, 0.015, 0.015 ]
```

Changing the `scale` value will affect how big the item is on the ground. Remember that after saving changes, you'll need to reload your resource pack for changes to take effect. Here is a little explanation on how to change these values :

- To make the item bigger, change all three values up.
- Translation affects where on the ground the item is.
- If you want it to be higher or lower, change the middle number.